# JSON.stringify/parse throw error when handling non-serializable context in react native

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native

There are some non serializable in my React Native 0.70 app which is passed in Context API to make them available to following components. Here is code for it:

```
const propsContext = React.createContext(null);
const propsVal = {
  //key:value. value is non serializable
  key = JSON.stringify(value), //stringify for non serializable
};
...
<propsContext.Provider value={propsVal}>
... 
</propsContext.Provider>
```

In component which may need retrieve a non serializable value:

```
const propsVal = useContext(propsContext);
const _value = JSON.parse(propsVal.key) // here it throw error unexpected token u
```

However it throws error in component:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected token: u
```

Any suggestion about how to handle this non serializable value on React context?

Comment: Can you try initialize your context ```const propsContext = React.createContext({key:””});``` or ```key = JSON.stringify({}),```